# Loading custom fonts at runtime for use with JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, internationalization, jtextpane

Thanks for your time. My question is regarding the display of different fonts within the one JTextPane. My client wishes to view a word in two different languages within the one field. They've explicitly specified that they wish the different languages (namely Amharic, Arabic, Coptic and Hebrew) to be shown with different fonts. These are obviously non-standard fonts and I can't rely on the user having the required fonts installed on their OS.

From my research I've found that I can load a font file at runtime and set the JTextPane's font accordingly, which is fine if I just wanted to use one font, not two. I've also read about adding fonts to the OS' font directory or the JRE's font directory, outlined [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/addingfonts.html#fonts).

I was hoping however, that there might be away to use the fonts without altering the user's OS. Am I out of luck?

Thanks again for your time and I look forward to any replies with bright ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From my research I've found that I can load a font file at runtime and set the JTextPane's font accordingly, which is fine if I just wanted to use one font, not two.

A JTextPane can use multiple fonts.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for an example of playing with the attributes of the text in the text pane.

Edit:

> However to use multiple fonts, the only way I have worked out to set the font is by creating a MutableAttributeSet and setting the "FontFamily" attribute (a string) to the desired font name, and then assigning the Attribute set to the text using the StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes

Reading the API for the createFont() method it looks like you should be able to use:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont(Font)
```

Comment: Hi Camickr, thanks for your reply! You are quite right, you can use multiple fonts with a JTextPane. 

However I've only been able to find code to use fonts already installed on the OS, where as what I want to be able to do is load custom fonts at runtime (ie. the fonts are resources in my jar).

If there was away to point the JVM's font path to another folder or register another directory as a font folder, that would be great.

Comment: You stated that you can load a font file at runtime and set the JTextPane's font. That is why I highlighted that statement in my answer. So if you know how to load one font why can't you load two fonts?

Comment: Fair point. Well, the way I've successfully used one custom font, is by reading in a ttf file with the `FontFont.createFont` mehtod and then setting the JTextPane's font property, `JTextPane.setFont`. However to use multiple fonts, the only way I have worked out to set the font is by creating a `MutableAttributeSet` and setting the "FontFamily" attribute (a string) to the desired font name, and then assigning the Attribute set to the text using the `StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes` method, as shown [here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/setting-jtextpane-font-and-color/)

Comment: ...this work fine, _as long as_ the font that you reference is installed on the OS. So you see, my problem is that I want to use fonts that are **not** installed on the OS.
Thanks

Comment: YAHTZEE! Camickr, you dead-set legend! I don't know how I hadn't come across that method in my travels, but thank you! As an unexpected bonus, loading fonts in this fashion lets you use them with all HTML-friendly Swing components.