# How to create a simple Paragraph class

Tags: java, swing, text, document, jtextpane

I've been trying to create a class which can do the following:
• Set: **Font**, **Alignment** (left, center, right, justified)
• An efficient way to `append` text to the document.
The text does not need to be selectable or editable.
I have to be able to override the painting / rendering of the text.

I find that the JDK `JTextComponent` classes are difficult to use efficiently, as this is what I have so far but it is far from what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Paragraph extends JTextPane{

    public Paragraph(){
        this.setFont(Fonts.PARAGRAPH);
        this.setOpaque(false);
    }

   // ridiculously slow
   public void append(String s) {
     SimpleAttributeSet def = new SimpleAttributeSet();
     StyleConstants.setForeground(def, Colors.PARAGRAPH);
     Document d = getDocument();
     try {
       d.insertString(d.getLength(), s, def);
     } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
   }
 }  
}
```

**Question:** Are there any libraries which could save me time re-inventing the wheel?
 If not, how can I go about extending the JDK implementations? Thanks

Comment: _save me time re-inventing the wheel?_ simple: don't ;-) What's the problem that you think needs fixing? What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: forgot: _never_ subclass for mere configuration

Comment: @kleopatra can you explain your second comment a bit more please?

Comment: @kleopatra Note that comments can be edited for 5 mins.  (that was only 3 minutes, by the looks of it).

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah, I know - but annoyed by being told after typing and trying to commit "sorry, gal, your five minutes are over, type again :-)

Comment: don't know what there could be possibly explained - it's basic OO :-)

Comment: @kleopatra Well obviously I know what subclass mean, but what do you mean by mere configuration, and more importantly why not?

Comment: no offense meant - but _mere configuration, and more importantly why not_ if you don't know why you shouldn't subclass when you could reach the same without subclassing ... you don't know overly much about OO ;-) I would suggest you read up in some textbook - that will explain the basics much better than I could in 300+ characters

Comment: @kleopatra so you're saying that if I want to create a large amount of `Paragraphs`, using them in several classes, I'll have to set the opacity, attributes, font, foreground, etc. of a `JTextPane` every time? Where's the sense in that? Subclassing isn't a bad thing from an abstraction point of view. Makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: obviously you are free to stick to whatever makes perfect sense to you, be it an error or not ;-)

Comment: You can't claim that a preference is an error without saying **why** it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Document should be StyledDocument instance. Then just use setParagraphAttributes() method of the Document instance.

For multiple appends use a separate document (not set to the JTextPane instance.

Use the kit ot create a new empty Document instance. Call all your appends and then setDocument(theDocInstance) to the JTextPane.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Okay that is nice and quick, though I'm not sure how to set the `Font` now? I could look it up though. Thanks.

Comment: You insert String with attributes like you did before. After the String is inserted you apply paragraph attributes to the inserted fragment via setParagraphAttributes() method.

Comment: But there is not `setFont` in a `SimpleAttributeSet`?

Comment: See StyleConstants.setFontFamily()

Comment: See camickr's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800683/loading-custom-fonts-at-runtime-for-use-with-jtextpane

Comment: Also see reference: http://javatechniques.com/blog/setting-jtextpane-font-and-color/